# Why is my reactive expression not filtering data correctly?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to filter a large ecology csv by column with a selectInput in a shiny app, but when I run the app it still returns all datapoints and not just the ones in the specified column. I think the filter function is not recognizing the input$spec argument and ignoring it completely, but I'm not sure as I am new to R and Rshiny.

```
rtdata <- read.csv("../data/2021_2022_rt_data.csv")

#rename as an intermediate df so that we retain rtdata
plants <- rtdata2022

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Submerged Macrophyte Density"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("spec", "Plant Species",
                  c("Algae" = "Algae",
                    "American Eelgrass" = "AmericanEelgrass"),
                  selected = "AmericanEelgrass"
                  )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("graph")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  filtered_plants <- reactive({
    req(input$spec)
    plants %>%
      filter(input$spec >= 1, Submerged.Macrophyte.Density !="")
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_plants(), aes(Rake.Toss.Density))+
      geom_bar(stat = "count")+
      labs(title = "Species Submerged Macrophyte Density")+
      theme_classic()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So, to elaborate further, instead of the ggplot graph showing just the Rake Toss Densitys for the selected species type, it is showing all data points across all species, as there is a column for zero which should be removed by the filter function. This could be a very dumb fix, I am just new to coding, so I apologize in advance. For reference, the species are their own columns, and presence in a given sample is indicated by a "1" or "0" if missing, which should explain the filter idea further. I have gotten this filtering method to work without the input$ structure required by shiny but I want to be able to toggle between species.

[output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmPYM.png)

Comment: As your `selectInput` returns the name of a column you have to do `filter(.data[[input$spec]] >= 1, ...)`. Otherwise `input$spec` is simply treated as a character string. i..e you are checking e.g. `"Algae" >= 1` which returns `TRUE`.

Comment: ... See e.g. https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#example-dplyr for more on the `.data` pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you are effectively comparing a string to a value (e.g. `"Algae" >= 1` this translates to `"Algae" >= "1"` which always yields `TRUE` (same for `"AmericanEelgrass" >= 1`). What you want is to use the string `"Algae"` to select the corresponding column.

There are several ways of doing this:

```r
library(dplyr)

spec <- "am"

mtcars %>% filter(spec >= 1) %>% nrow() ## won't work
# [1] 32

## Option 1: using `.data` pronoun
mtcars %>% filter(.data[[spec]] >= 1) %>% nrow()
# [1] 13

## Option 2: using tidy eval syntax
mtcars %>% filter(!!sym(spec) >= 1) %>% nrow()
# [1] 13
```